# Minecraft world has lost everything in latest Bedrock edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can someone help me on this issue? I am not sure what to do. The world is the exact same as when I started it.

Comment: This might sound like a dumb question but are you sure you clicked the right world and are in the right place?

Comment: Could the world have been corrupted?

Comment: It's uncertain what the context is in this question, so it seems reasonable that we can't answer this yet. Did you update your game? How long did you last play the world? We need context.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this is probably due to corruption of your save. Unless you have a backup, there probably isn't much you can do. If the file was on a Realm, realms have versioned backups you could try restoring.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why this could be:

1. Corrupted Save

- Whilst saving your world, there might've been a problem that caused corrupting what was inside that world.
- You can read [**@peabody**'s answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/381114/minecraft-world-has-lost-everything-in-latest-bedrock-edition/381377#381377) if you want more info.

Comment: This doesn't really add any to the other answer